# sharing tables from different databases in drupal 7 for a multisite

Tags: drupal-7

I am building a drupal multisite, say childone and childtwo. Both have their separate databases. Now the requirement is to share some of the tables, eg. a user created in site childone must have the same access permissions in site childtwo also. 
Can please anyone suggest me with the proper Stepwise solution ?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

You need to use table prefixes, and settings.php explains how to accomplish this:

```
 * You can optionally set prefixes for some or all database table names
 * by using the 'prefix' setting. If a prefix is specified, the table
 * name will be prepended with its value. Be sure to use valid database
 * characters only, usually alphanumeric and underscore. If no prefixes
 * are desired, leave it as an empty string ''.
 *
 * To have all database names prefixed, set 'prefix' as a string:
 * @code
 *   'prefix' => 'main_',
 * @endcode
 * To provide prefixes for specific tables, set 'prefix' as an array.
 * The array's keys are the table names and the values are the prefixes.
 * The 'default' element is mandatory and holds the prefix for any tables
 * not specified elsewhere in the array. Example:
 * @code
 *   'prefix' => array(
 *     'default'   => 'main_',
 *     'users'     => 'shared_',
 *     'sessions'  => 'shared_',
 *     'role'      => 'shared_',
 *     'authmap'   => 'shared_',
 *   ),
 * @endcode
```

So for your example, for your childone site's settings.php, you'd have something like the following:

```
'prefix' => array(
  'default'    => 'childone_',
  'user'       => 'shared_',
  'sessions'   => 'shared_',
  'role'       => 'shared_',
  'permission' => 'shared_',
);
```

And for childtwo's settings.php, it's very similar:

```
'prefix' => array(
  'default'    => 'childtwo_',
  'user'       => 'shared_',
  'sessions'   => 'shared_',
  'role'       => 'shared_',
  'permission' => 'shared_',
);
```

All tables will be prefixed with either childone_ or childtwo_ except the shared ones, which will be prefixed with shared_ (or whatever you want) after running the installation.

Comment: Thanks a lot web drics Webdrips, the same i tried to implement but it invokes an error each time i refresh the webpage.
The error corrosponds to something like file not found or an error related to .inc files.

Comment: The settings.php file for childone and childtwo looks exactly the same that u have posted, may be there is some other setting that needs to be done.
If u can please elaborate a bit stepwise.
Thanks a tonn in Advance.

Comment: Well you can take a look here: http://drupal.org/node/22267
Can you post the actual error message?
There's a lot of other steps to getting a multisite working; have you ever done a multisite before? Or are you only struggling with the shared tables?